# Calculating coefficients of generating function

Tags: probability, generating-functions

Fist I'll explain the problem I had to solve (and which I solved), and then ask a related question.

We have a bin with 2 balls: black and white. We take one from the bin and put back.
Than we add a black ball into the bin (so there are 3 balls: 1 white and 2 blacks).
Then we take a ball from the bin and put back.
These adding balls and taking one of them repeats again and again, until we exhaust all the attempts we have.

I had to calculate the probability that the overall count of taken white balls is bigger than the one of black balls.

For simplicity lets take 4 attempts (in the real task this figure was much bigger).

To solve the problem I decided to use generating function.
For the first attempt the probability to pick white is $p=1/2$, and to pick a black is $q=1/2$.

The second attempt gives this figures: $p=1/3$, $q=2/3$.

Third: $p=1/4$, $q=3/4$.

And so on.

So, the generating function is: 
$$G = (1/2+1/2 \cdot z)(2/3+1/3 \cdot z)(3/4+1/4 \cdot z)(4/5+1/5 \cdot z) = \\
=1/5+5/12 \cdot z+7/24 \cdot z^2+1/12 \cdot z^3+1/120 \cdot z^4$$

To calculate that we took more white balls than black we sum up coefficients before $z^3$ and $z^4$ and get $11/120$.

I implemented it into the algorithm for it to be able to process arbitrary number of attempts. To extract the coefficients I calculated corresponding derivatives and calculated them at $z=0$. For example to get $1/12$ before $z^3$, I did this:
$$\frac {1}{3!} \cdot\frac {d^{3}G}{dz^{3}}\bigg|_{z=0} = 1/12$$.

Then I summed all the needed coefficients.

The problem is that I had to use **symbolic** math.

How I can avoid using symbolic calculation and use just numeric calculation to calculate the needed coefficients?

May be there is a way to do it without a generating function at all? Maybe there exist other formulas, which are better for numeric calculations?

Answer (score 1):

You can find numerical *approximations* to derivatives of a function $G$ by observing that e.g. $\frac1h(G(h)-G(0))$ is an approximation for $G'(0)$. In fact,  $\frac1h(G(h)-G(0))=G'(\xi)$ for some $\xi$ with $0<\xi<h$ by the mean value theorem. Approximations for higher derivatives can be obtained from higher differences, e.g. $\frac{G(2h)-2G(h)+G(0)}{h^2}\approx G''(0)$ and similar alternating sums with binomial coefficients work for even higher derivatives.
Note however, that you should not simply plug in a very small value of $h$ and take the calculated value for granted. Because of the nearly cancelling subtractions, a lot of precision is lost this way! Rather  make calculations for several small but not too small values of $h$ and use methods of *numerical extrapolation*.

Answer (score 1):

you can calculate the coefficient using conv in matlab
for example
a= [1/2 1/2]
b= [2/3 1/3]
c = conv(a,b)
then d = [3/4 1/4]
e = conv(c,d)

continue ( you can write as for loop)
Then you get coefficients for all terms from high power to low power

Comment: Thank you! This it closer to an answer I would like to accept. Still, I expect that there could be a way to completely get rid of generating function (as I understand it's designed just to simplify things for those who make by-hand calculations), as there might be other formulas using for example binomial coefficients (it's just a guess).

Comment: But yes, `conv` is much closer to numeric calculation of the probabilities than resorting to numeric approximate calculations of derivatives of the generating function as suggested in the other answer.